# Проблема со сборкой проекта с подключенной локальной библиотекой

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, build

у меня такая проблема, у меня есть локальная библиотека в виде jar файла, я подключил ее к проекту просто через pom.xml, в котором указал scope = system и путь. Когда я запускаю проект в idea - все работает, когда я сбираю проект в jar файл, а потом запускаю, у меня исключения по типу ClassNotFoundException, для классов как раз таки из локальной библиотеки. Как можно это решить?

Пробовал удалять проблемные классы.

Answer (score 0):

*Удаление* "проблемных" файлов не слишком подходит для решения проблемы с `ClassNotFoundException`.

Согласно [документации Мaven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) и её [переводу](https://java-online.ru/maven-faq.xhtml#scope)

> Область действия зависимости `scope` определяет этап жизненного цикла проекта, в котором эта зависимость будет использоваться. Maven использует 6 областей :
> ...
>
> - **`provided`** - очень похоже на `compile`, но эта зависимость в сборку не попадает. Предполагается, что зависимость (артефакт) уже присутствует в JDK или в WEB-контейнере. Эта область доступна только на этапах компиляции и тестирования и не является транзитивной;
>   ...
> - **`system`** - область похожа на `provided` за исключением того, что необходимо определить физическое расположение артефакта на диске. Артефакт с этой областью видимости maven не ищет в репозитории;

Кроме того, этот параметр является [устаревшим](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#system-dependencies).
Ранее он применялся для ссылок на `.jar`-файлы, которые *теперь* предоставляются JDK или VM, например расширения JDBC `javax.sql`:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Таким образом, если используется `system`, то следует гарантировать, что `.jar`-файл с соответствующими классами будет находиться где-то  в соответствующей директории, на которую указывает `systemPath` (вероятно, потребуется жёстко закодировать полный путь к `jar`-файлу).

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>grillid9.laslib</groupId>
  <artifactId>loveLas</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>C:\mylib\loveLas-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

И соответствующий .jar должен копироваться строго в указанную директорию.

---

Вероятно, всё же проще/разумнее следовало бы использовать значение `scope` по умолчанию `compile`, тогда соответствующая зависимость станет доступна, так как библиотечные классы будут запакованы в тот же `.jar` файл, что и основное приложение, или хотя бы `scope = provided`, тогда можно было бы предоставить доступ к библиотеке через параметр `classpath`.

Comment: Указал путь на локальную библиотеку через "-cp" ошибка не исчезла. Вот кусок ошибки:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grillid9.laslib.Curve
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149) ~[geodrilling.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        ... 61 common frames omitted

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>grillid9.laslib</groupId>
   <artifactId>loveLas</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/loveLas-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>

Так у меня подключается библиотека в pom.xml

Comment: Запускаю программу так: java -cp lovelas.jar -jar geodrilling.jar
если что  lovelas.jar и geodrilling.jar лежат в той же директории, из которой запускаю

Comment: Похоже, что ответ был не слишком верен.  Во-первых, [`scope=system` устарел](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#system-dependencies).  Во-вторых, его следует использовать для зависимостей, которые предоставляет именно JDK типа `<systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>`, у вас же используется некая собственная библиотека, для которой вероятно лучше подошёл бы `scope=provided`.